# metada conflict when deploying Openstack on GCP

Tags: openstack, cloud-init, metadata, tripleo, gcp

We ran an openstack environnement on GCP with an arch of 1control_1compute_2ceph.
When creating VM on openstack, the VM can't initialte the cloud-init, because wit reaches the metadata of GCP instead of private openstack.
The openstack is the last version from tripleo. It uses OVN networking.
Is there any way to reeach openstack 169.254.169.254 instead of the GCP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found this hope can help
Instances are directly attached to the provider external networks, and have external routers configured as their default gateway. No OpenStack Networking (neutron) routers are used. This means that neutron routers cannot be used to proxy metadata requests from instances to the nova-metadata server, which may result in failures while running cloud-init. However, this issue can be resolved by configuring the dhcp agent to proxy metadata requests. You can enable this functionality in /etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini. For example:

```
enable_isolated_metadata = True
```

Answer (score 0):

While OpenStack on GCP is not a use case currently accounted for by cloud-init, you could always force which datasource gets used by cloud-init using kernel commandline arguments (`ds=openstack`), or by manually setting the datasource list: `datasource_list: [openstack]`.